# Error de llamada a Fill

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms, combobox

Cree un método de filtrado para un **ComboBox**, pero cuando selecciono algún item de la colección del **ComboBox** sale este error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'No se ha inicializado la propiedad SelectCommand antes de llamar a 'Fill'.'
```

Este es el método de filtrado:

```
private void filtroGenero() {
        if (cmbGenero.SelectedIndex == 0) {
            llenarId();
        }else{
            try {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                string conn = "cadena de conexion";
                using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(conn)) {
                    conexion.Open();
                    string sSQL = "SELECT id, nombre, celular,url FROM clientesDos WHERE genero = @param";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sSQL, conexion);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", Convert.ToInt32(cmbGenero.SelectedIndex));
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                    da.Fill(dt);
                }
                dtgId.DataSource = dt;
            } catch (SqlException ex) {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message,"Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
```

¿Alguna solución posible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal y como te indica el error, debes asociar un `command` a la propiedad `SelectCommand` del `DataAdapter`.

Puedes verlo en la [documentación oficial de Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter?view=netframework-4.8).

Puedes hacerlo como bien te ha dicho @Pikoh, o se la siguiente manera:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string conn = "cadena de conexion";
using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(conn)) 
{
    conexion.Open();
    string sSQL = "SELECT id, nombre, celular,url FROM clientesDos WHERE genero = @param";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sSQL, conexion);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", Convert.ToInt32(cmbGenero.SelectedIndex));
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    da.Fill(dt);
}
dtgId.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 2):

Estas creando un `Sqlcommand`, pero no se lo asignas al `DataAdapter` con lo que este último no sabe que hacer.

Puedes usar la sobrecarga del constructor de `DataAdapter` que recibe un `Sqlcommand`:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
```

Comment: Gracias, no me había percatado de ese detalle. Muchas gracias